# For of and click event in es6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

if I use jquery it's working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('btn').click(function() {
       alert('start');
   });
});
```

but I want use native es6

```
window.onload = function() {
    let btn = document.getElementsByClassName( 'btn' );
    for (let i of btn.length) {
        i.onclick( function () {
            alert( 'start' );
        });
    }
};
```

error btn.length[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

And this doesn't work too.

```
window.onload = function() {
    let btn = document.getElementsByClassName( 'btn' );
    for (let i=0; i < btn.length; i++) {

        i.onclick = function () {
            alert( 'start' );
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Second one should be `btn[i].onclick=...` not `i.onclick` .. `i` is a number not an element

Comment: `for... of` iterates a collection - so `for(let btn of buttons) { ...` and not `of buttons.length`

Answer (score 6):

The `for of` loop will iterate over the elements of a collection that has a `[Symbol.iterator]` property. In your ES6 snippet you are trying to iterate over the returned HTMLCollection length eg. `for (let i of btn.length)...`.

Here is what you should do instead.

```js
let btns = document.getElementsByClassName( 'btn' );

for ( let btn of btns ) {
  btn.onclick = function() {
    console.clear()
    console.log(this.textContent)
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Btn 1</button>
<button class="btn">Btn 2</button>
<button class="btn">Btn 3</button>
<button class="btn">Btn 4</button>
```

Comment: And what is the advantage of converting NodeList to an Array ? How that advantage overweight allocation of new array in heap ?

Comment: I did not read the question correctly and actually did not know that `for of` even performs better than `forEach`. Thanks for the hint.